# Angular Routing or. .Net Core Redirection, which should be preferred for authentication?

Tags: .net, angular, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am a beginner full stack developer. I want to make a simple login authentication system. I am using `.Net Core 3.0` in backend and `Angular 8` in frontend, `MsSQL Server` in db.

I implemented a Web API which provide `Sign up` functionality(my problem is about `Sign in` authentication). I also implemented a page for `Sign in` and `Sign up` UI with `Angular`.

If user type a true password when `Signing in`, I should redirect/route to page "Dashboard".

If user type a true password when `Signing in`, I shouldn't redirect/route anywhere.

I think that I found two approach for solving this problem.

First one is, `POST` email and password which are typed by user to API, check the typed password is true for the typed email in database and if it is true, then redirect to dashboard page. Shortly make the check in backend(`.Net Core 3.0`). 
Example is this:

```
public IActionResult checkPasswordIsTrue(){

if (tpyedPassword == realPassword)
{
     return Redirect("http://192.168.1.22:4200/dashboard");
}
```

Second one is, `POST` email and password which are typed by user to API, `GET` from the real password for the typed email. Then check the typed password is true and if it is true(with using `canActivate` conditional routing) route to dashboard page.Shortly make the check in frontend(`Angular`). 
Example is this:

`HTML`:

```
 <button mat-raised-button (click)="signIn()" color="primary" routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active" >Sign in</button>
```

and `TypeScipt` file:

```
signIn(): void {
    this.httpClient.get(`http://192.168.1.35:32450/user/${this.user.email}`).subscribe(
      (dbPassword:any)=>{
        if(dbPassword==this.user.password){
           isActivate=true; //so go to dashboard
        }
      }
    )
```

Which approach is true? If both of them is true, which one is more effective? 
What is best practise approach for this kind of problem?

Comment: So in the second approach, you return the actual password to the client and check on the client? If so that is definitely wrong. Your passwords should be hashed such that your second option is impossible to implement. Furthermore, the client actually should redirect, but only based on the server-side side signin result

Comment: @AluanHaddad I see then what do you think about first approach?

Comment: It's better, but see the last part of my comment. Basically, if authentication fails, your server should return a response with a `401` status code and the client should handle that by not allowing the user to proceed. Bear in mind that client side checks like these are soft checks that help guide the user. They don't comprise security. You need to ensure authentication/authorization every time you fetch data that shouldn't be public.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Okay, thanks a lot. I understand that I need to check authentication in backend which is like in first approach and I  should return a response to Client like 401 or Success(depends on authentication result.) Could I understand correctly?

Comment: Yeah, that's right. Since your login UI is written in angular, you don't need to return a redirect from your server, let the client handle that. But please remember  not to store unencrypted passwords in the database.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Okay, thanks a lot again. I'll keep in my mind that.